# Boot Linux Mint Partition from VirtualBox on Windows, don't seem to have /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc

Tags: windows, virtualbox, grub, x86

I'm trying to boot a regular Linux partition from VirtualBox on Windows. I found [this](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329) tutorial and followed it. Basically, this just creates an ISO file of the GRUB configuration so that VirtualBox can simply read the partition as if it was a normal virtual machine. However, when it comes to creating an ISO, I don't seem to have `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc`, as the tutorial requires.

The only folders I have in `/usr/lib/grub/` are called `x86_64-efi` and `x86_64-efi-signed`. I did try to create an ISO from both of those but without luck.

I have Windows 10 installed on one SSD and then installed Mint 19 in dual boot configuration on another SSD. My GRUB version is `2.02-2ubuntu8.9`, so it is the latest.

Comment: google `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc`

Comment: I tried that but i couldn't find anything about why I don't have that folder

Comment: yes, but you can find information about how to obtain the folder and its contents

Comment: I honestly couldn't. I couldn't even find what it is good for. Whatever I search for, I always find the same StackExchange entries that talk about a different problem.